# Raspberry Pi Zero W with SparkFun Pulse Oximeter and Heart Rate Monitor (MAX30101 and MAX32664 )

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w

I am trying to read data by connecting Raspberry Pi Zero W with SparkFun Pulse Oximeter and Heart Rate Monitor (MAX30101 and MAX32664). SparkFun has provided the code for [Arduino Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Bio_Sensor_Hub_Library/tree/master/src)

Any suggestions on how to create or convert a python code based on the .cpp or .h code file in the Arduino Library?

Thank you.

Comment: start by reading the MAX30101 and MAX32664 datasheets

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.